# Highlight questions in the star list when I hover over the reply

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars, reply

When I hover over a reply, I get a nice effect that clearly shows me which post it is replying to:

[image: I'm not actually that boring!]

It would be really nice if this effect happened in the star list too:

[image]

Stars (sometimes) hang around for a while, so to work out where a reply goes involves loading up the transcript in another tab, just to find out it's a starred message.